# Python redis client zrangebylex

Tags: python, redis, sortedset

I want to perform the following command using the python client of redis

```
zrangebylex names_sorted_set [a "[a\xff\xff\xff\xff"
```

but in my code the following cases happen

```
    name = request.GET.get('name', '')
    redis_con = redis.StrictRedis(settings.REDIS_HOST, settings.REDIS_PORT)
    min = '[' + name
    max = '[' + name + """\xff\xff"""
    result = redis_con.zrangebylex('names_sorted_set', min, max)
```

Above code gives me this error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)...
I tried another piece of code which is

```
    redis_con = redis.StrictRedis(settings.REDIS_HOST, settings.REDIS_PORT)
    min = '[' + name
    max = '[' + name + """\\xff\\xff"""
    result = redis_con.zrangebylex('names_sorted_set', min, max)
```

and The last one gives this to redis as the command:

```
zrangebylex names_sorted_set [a "[a\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff"
```

PS: The code is meant to find all the strings in a sorted set which start with a specifix prefix eg:a.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked

```
    name = request.GET.get('name', '')
    redis_con = redis.StrictRedis(settings.REDIS_HOST, settings.REDIS_PORT)
    min = '[' + name
    max = bytearray('[') + \
          bytearray(name, 'utf-8') + \
          b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
    result = redis_con.zrangebylex('names_sorted_set', min, max)
```